# Return multiple types with Tuple<T1,T2>

Tags: c#

I need a static function like this :

```
public static class Output
{
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Output(T1 out1, T2 out2)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(out1,out2);
    }
}
```

But the function has syntax errors. Anyone can help?

**NOTE** I mean :

```
retun Output("asd", 10);
return Output(myclassInstance, date);

... instead of below

return new Tuple<string, int>("asd", 10);
return new Tuple<Myclass, DateTime>(myclassInstance, date);
```

Comment: "But the function has syntax errors."  why didn't you include them then?  Is this supposed to be a guessing game?

Comment: `public static Tuple<T1, T2> Output<T1, T2>(T1 out1, T2 out2)`: You're missing the generic type definitions after the method name

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to Generic! Thanks

Comment: Emphasis: there's no reason for this method to exist - it is exactly what `Tuple.Create` does

Comment: Also note that despite the question being tagged c#-7.0, you're not using any of the C# 7 tuple-related features here. Those use `ValueTuple<...>`, not `Tuple<...>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have been away from programming 3 years! I'm Alzheimer's now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the method generic:

```
public static Tuple<T1, T2> YourMethod<T1, T2>(T1 out1, T2 out2)
{
    return new Tuple<T1, T2>(out1,out2);
}
```

However... all of this is just the `Tuple.Create` method-group - so:

```
return YourMethod("asd", 10);
```

is the same as:

```
return Tuple.Create("asd", 10);
```

As a side note, you might want to consider `ValueTuple<...>` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/). In addition to being more efficient, there is inbuilt language support in latest language versions. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-tuples

Answer (score 1):

1. The method must not have the same name as the class.
2. The method needs to be generic (have type parameters)

   `public static Tuple<T1, T2> Output<T1, T2>(T1 out1, T2 out2)`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C#7 (according to your tags), you might want to consider doing it like this:

```
public static (T1 out1, T2 out2) Output<T1, T2>(T1 out1, T2 out2)
{
    return (out1, out2);
}
```

In this case it seems likely that you can give the tuple elements better names than `out1` and `out2`.

However, at this point it seems even more likely that you could forego this wrapper method altogether, and just use the C#7 "Tuple Return" language feature directly where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is such builtin function (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,9124c4bea9ab0199):

```
    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) 
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(item1, item2);
    }
```